# Fazer loop se ferir condição

Tags: javascript

Eu gostaria que fosse solicitado ao usuário uma mensagem para que o mesmo digite um número, caso esse numero for verdadeiro, será exibida uma tela informando o número digitado.

Caso o usuário digite uma letra, será exibida uma mensagem informando que ele digitou um número inválido e para que digite novamente.

Porém não sei como faço para ficar em *loop* até que ele digite um número verdadeiro.

Abaixo deixo as minhas tentativas.

```
var num1 = prompt('digite um numero');
if (isNaN(num1)) {
  document.write('numero invalido digite novamente')
}
```

Fiz o mesmo código usando funções, mas gostaria de saber se existe outra forma.

Código usando funções:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    <script>


        digite();

        var num1;
        function digite() {
            num1 = prompt('digite um numero');

         // caso usuario digite um numero inválido //
            if (isNaN(num1)) {
                alert('numero invalido digite novamente');
                digite();
            }
        }
        //caso usuário digite um numero válido //
        document.write("o numero digitado foi " + num1)
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basta usar um laço de repetição. A lógica é simples:

- Antes de iniciar o laço, crie uma variável com a resposta inicial do usuário.
- Enquanto a resposta estiver incorreta, faça a *pergunta* novamente até que esteja correta.
- Uma vez que a resposta estiver correta, deixe de executar o laço de repetição.

Você pode atingir isso com um laço `while`:

```js
function getResponse() {
  const data = prompt('Digite um número <= 5');

  // Adicione a lógica de validação aqui.
  if (parseInt(data) <= 5) {
    return data;
  }

  return false;
}

let resp = getResponse();

// Enquanto a resposta estiver inválida, execute o bloco de código.
while (resp === false) {
  alert('Tente de novo...');
  // Note que devemos atribuir à resposta uma outra "tentativa",
  // já que após cada iteração (incorreta), o usuário deve tentar novamente.
  resp = getResponse();
}

console.log('Resposta final:', resp);
```

Mas também pode fazer usando o `for`, se preferir. Só acho um pouco menos intuitivo:

```js
function getResponse() {
  const data = prompt('Digite um número <= 5');

  // Adicione a lógica de validação aqui.
  if (parseInt(data) <= 5) {
    return data;
  }

  return false;
}

// Como precisamos de acessar a `resp` de fora do loop (após ele),
// não podemos declarar essa variável na declaração do `for`.
let resp = getResponse();

for (; !resp; resp = getResponse()) {
  alert('Tente de novo...');
}

console.log('Resposta final:', resp);
```

Se você for reutilizar essa funcionalidade, pode até criar uma função *wrapper*:

```js
function getResponse({ getter, validator, onError, onSuccess }) {
  let resp = getter();
  let isValid = validator(resp);

  while (!isValid) {
    onError(resp);

    // "Rodar" novamente:
    resp = getter();
    isValid = validator(resp);
  }

  onSuccess(resp);
}

getResponse({
  getter: () => prompt('Digite um número menor ou igual a 5.'),
  validator: (resp) => parseInt(resp) <= 5,
  onError: (resp) => alert(`O valor "${resp}" não é válido.`),
  onSuccess: (resp) => alert(`Acertou! O número ${resp} é válido!`)
});
```

Comment: Obrigado. Eu tinha duvida sobre isso. Ainda bem que achei essa pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

Uma forma simples, também utilizando `while` e uma função `verifica` que retorna um objeto com dois dados:

```
function verifica(n){
   return { num: n, isan: !isNaN(n) };
             ↑       ↑
       caractere    verifica se é um número: 'true' se for número
        digitado
}
```

O `while`:

```
var ver;
while(!ver){
   var num1 = verifica(prompt('digite um numero'));
   var vnum = num1.num || '';
   ver = vnum.trim().length ? num1.isan : 0;
   !ver ? alert('numero invalido digite novamente') : num1 = vnum;
}
```

Declara a variável `ver` inicialmente sem valor (*false*), e enquanto ela for `false` o `while` irá rodar.

A variável `num1` recebe o objeto de retorno da função.

A variável `vnum` será o valor da chave `num` do objeto de retorno da função ou será uma string vazia (`''`) caso o usuário tente cancelar ou fechar o prompt.

O valor de `ver` irá mudar de acordo com o retorno da função: se o que foi digitado no prompt tiver pelo menos 1 caractere, o valor de `ver` será o valor da chave `isan` do objeto retornado da função, caso contrário será igual a `0`, que é `false`.

Com isso, na última linha do `while`, se `ver` for *false* (`!ver`) irá disparar o alerta e continuar a rodar o while, se não, irá alterar o valor da variável `num1` para o que foi digitado no prompt, sair do while (pois `!ver` já não é mais `false`) e imprimir o resultado na tela (`document.write`).

**Veja:**

```js
function verifica(n){
   return { num: n, isan: !isNaN(n) };
}

var ver;
while(!ver){
   var num1 = verifica(prompt('digite um numero'));
   var vnum = num1.num || '';
   ver = vnum.trim().length ? num1.isan : 0;
   !ver ? alert('numero invalido digite novamente') : num1 = vnum;
}
document.write("o numero digitado foi " + num1);
```